# how to pass variables into Teradata fastexport

Tags: teradata, fastexport

my Bteq file code(test_bteq) is

`select * from students where student.id between &start and $end.`

the bteq sql is scheduled everyday and  these 2 variables from 2 columns of a configuration table(tab_conf).
I need to use `&start` and `$end` variables in bteq file.

Comment: BTEQ or FastExport?

Comment: Teradata fastexport

Comment: `.ACCEPT` can read values from a file or an enviromement variable. Btw, FastExport is legacy and all new development should switch to TPT.

Comment: .ACCEPT Left,Right FROM file_test; I use this,but I got errors.

Comment: Which exact error messages?